# Pyspark update two columns using one when statement?

Tags: python, pyspark

So I am using `df.Withcolumn()` in PySpark to create a column and using `F.when()` to specify the criteria as to when the column should be updated.

```
df = df.withColumn('ab', F.when(df['text']=="0", 1).otherwise(0))
```

Basically I am updating the column to be '1' if it matches the criteria. Now, I want to update another column in the same `df` if the same criteria matches (eg. `df['text']=="0"`). Is there any way in PySpark to update two columns using one when statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. You can only created struct:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df.withColumn('ab', F.when(df['text']=="0" , struct(1, "foo")).otherwise(struct(0, "bar")))
```